# braintree hosted fields not rendering fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, material-design, braintree

I am trying to use the material design braintree hosted fields, I can get the html to render, but is appears as if I have some issue with the javascript conflicting or similar

```
<!-- Material Design inspired Hosted Fields theme -->

<!-- Icons are taken from the material design library https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/ -->

<!--[if IE 9]>
<style>

  .panel {
    margin: 2em auto 0;
  }

</style>
<![endif]-->

<form id="cardForm">
  <div class="panel">
    <header class="panel__header">
      <h1>Card Payment</h1>
    </header>

    <div class="panel__content">
      <div class="textfield--float-label">


        <label class="hosted-field--label" for="card-number"><span class="icon">
         <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><path d="M20 4H4c-1.11 0-1.99.89-1.99 2L2 18c0 1.11.89 2 2 2h16c1.11 0 2-.89 2-2V6c0-1.11-.89-2-2-2zm0 14H4v-6h16v6zm0-10H4V6h16v2z"/></svg></span> Card Number
        </label>
        <div id="card-number" class="hosted-field"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="textfield--float-label">

        <label class="hosted-field--label" for="expiration-date">
           <span class="icon">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M9 11H7v2h2v-2zm4 0h-2v2h2v-2zm4 0h-2v2h2v-2zm2-7h-1V2h-2v2H8V2H6v2H5c-1.11 0-1.99.9-1.99 2L3 20c0 1.1.89 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V6c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zm0 16H5V9h14v11z"/></svg>
         </span>
          Expiration Date</label>
        <div id="expiration-date" class="hosted-field"></div>
      </div>


      <div class="textfield--float-label">
        <label class="hosted-field--label" for="cvv">
          <span class="icon">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M18 8h-1V6c0-2.76-2.24-5-5-5S7 3.24 7 6v2H6c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v10c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h12c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V10c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zm-6 9c-1.1 0-2-.9-2-2s.9-2 2-2 2 .9 2 2-.9 2-2 2zm3.1-9H8.9V6c0-1.71 1.39-3.1 3.1-3.1 1.71 0 3.1 1.39 3.1 3.1v2z"/></svg>
            </span>
          CVV</label>
        <div id="cvv" class="hosted-field"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="textfield--float-label">

        <label class="hosted-field--label" for="postal-code">
           <span class="icon">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path d="M12 2C8.13 2 5 5.13 5 9c0 5.25 7 13 7 13s7-7.75 7-13c0-3.87-3.13-7-7-7zm0 9.5c-1.38 0-2.5-1.12-2.5-2.5s1.12-2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.12 2.5 2.5-1.12 2.5-2.5 2.5z"/></svg>
         </span>
          Postal Code</label>
        <div id="postal-code" class="hosted-field"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="panel__footer">
      <button class="pay-button">Pay</button>
    </footer>
  </div>
</form>

<!-- Load the required client component. -->
<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/3.0.0-beta.9/js/client.min.js"></script>

<!-- Load Hosted Fields component. -->
<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/3.0.0-beta.9/js/hosted-fields.min.js"></script>

<script>braintree.client.create({ authorization: 'sandbox_g42y39zw_348pk9cgf3bgyw2b' }, function (err, clientInstance) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  braintree.hostedFields.create({
    client: clientInstance,
    styles: {
      'input': {
        'font-size': '16px',
        'font-family': 'roboto, verdana, sans-serif',
        'font-weight': 'lighter',
        'color': 'black'
      },
      ':focus': { 'color': 'black' },
      '.valid': { 'color': 'black' },
      '.invalid': { 'color': 'black' }
    },
    fields: {
      number: {
        selector: '#card-number',
        placeholder: '1111 1111 1111 1111'
      },
      cvv: {
        selector: '#cvv',
        placeholder: '111'
      },
      expirationDate: {
        selector: '#expiration-date',
        placeholder: 'MM/YY'
      },
      postalCode: {
        selector: '#postal-code',
        placeholder: '11111'
      }
    }
  }, function (err, hostedFieldsInstance) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return;
    }
    hostedFieldsInstance.on('focus', function (event) {
      var field = event.fields[event.emittedBy];
      $(field.container).next('.hosted-field--label').addClass('label-float').removeClass('filled');
    });
    hostedFieldsInstance.on('blur', function (event) {
      var field = event.fields[event.emittedBy];
      if (field.isEmpty) {
        $(field.container).next('.hosted-field--label').removeClass('label-float');
      } else if (event.isValid) {
        $(field.container).next('.hosted-field--label').addClass('filled');
      } else {
        $(field.container).next('.hosted-field--label').addClass('invalid');
      }
    });
    hostedFieldsInstance.on('empty', function (event) {
      var field = event.fields[event.emittedBy];
      $(field.container).next('.hosted-field--label').removeClass('filled').removeClass('invalid');
    });
    hostedFieldsInstance.on('validityChange', function (event) {
      var field = event.fields[event.emittedBy];
      if (field.isPotentiallyValid) {
        $(field.container).next('.hosted-field--label').removeClass('invalid');
      } else {
        $(field.container).next('.hosted-field--label').addClass('invalid');
      }
    });
    $('#cardForm').submit(function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      hostedFieldsInstance.tokenize(function (err, payload) {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
          return;
        }
        alert('Submit your nonce to your server here!');
      });
    });
  });
});
//# sourceURL=pen.js
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue was resolved by using the latest version of the JS SDK

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

In order to get this example to render properly, you need to include the proper dependencies (jQuery and MUI) as well as our stylesheet. If you export the CodePen as a zip file, the styling and dependencies should be included for you.

If you want the entire project in one HTML file, it should look something like [this example](https://gist.github.com/lilaconlee/d30a9d3e7441d45cd3b6ca07977f5265). The only differences between that in your code snippet are the inclusion of the jQuery and MUI script tags and our CSS.

Comment: within my application.js i have //= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require angular